# SQL Sort / Order By pivoted fields while COALESCE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some rates for resources for all countries
The rows will be Resource IDs
Columns should be Country Codes
Challenge here, I cannot sort the Country Codes in ASC
It would be so grateful if you could help me on this.

When I query, I get the list of country codes, but not sorted. i.e., USA,BRA,ARG etc. But the expected result should be ARG,BRA,USA in columns of the pivot.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @idList nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT
    @idList = COALESCE(@idList + ',', '') + CountryCodeISO3
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT CountryCodeISO3
        FROM
            Published.RateCardsValues
        WHERE
            CardID = 55
    ) AS SRC 
    
DECLARE @sqlToRun nvarchar(MAX)

SET
    @sqlToRun = '
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
       [ResourceCode]
      ,[TITLES]
      ,[MostRepresentativeTitle]
      ,[ABBR_RES_DESC]
      ,[TypicalJobGrade]
      ,[BidGridResourceCode]
      ,[OpUnit]
      ,[PSResType]
      ,[JobGradeORResCat]
      ,[CountryCodeISO3]
      --,[CurrencyCode]
      ,[RateValue]

    FROM 
        [Published].[RateCardsValues] rc
    WHERE 
        CardID = 55) As src
PIVOT ( 
    MAX(RateValue) FOR [CountryCodeISO3] IN (' + @idList + ')  
) AS pvt' 

EXEC (@sqlToRun)
```

Comment: FYI the syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and should be avoided. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using `STRING_AGG`, however, in older versions you'll need to use `FOR XML PATH` (and `STUFF`) to achieve the same results.

Comment: It's also generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: If you actually used `STRING_AGG` you can easily define the order of the values in the `ORDER BY` clause of the function's `WITHIN GROUP` clause.

Comment: Everything @Larnu said is absolutely right. All I want to add is: if you can live with the country codes being in rows, or if whatever you're receiving the data in can do the pivot for you (Excel and SSRS both can), you won't need to aggregate your IDs, build your SQL dynamically, or even use SQL's PIVOT statement.

Comment: Thanks Larnu and Ann, my SQL server version is 2016, hence I couldn't use STRING_AGG, however managed to do with STUFF and FOR XML PATH..

Comment: @gim_dev If one of the answers helped you (such as @Charlieface's) please consider marking it as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, PIVOT in T-SQL requires you to know *at development time* what the values will be that you will be pivoting on.

This is limiting, because if you want something like "retrieve data for all the countries where Condition X is true, then pivot on their IDs!", you have to resort to dynamic SQL to do it.

If Condition X is constant -- I'm guessing that belonging to CardID = 55 doesn't change often -- you can look up the values, and hardcode them in your code.

If the CardID you're looking up is always 55 and you have relatively few countries in that category, I'd actually advise doing that.

But if your conditions for picking countries can change, or the number of columns you want can vary -- something like "all the countries where there were sales of product Y, for month Z!" -- then you can't predict them, which means that the T-SQL PIVOT can't be set up (without dynamic SQL.)

In that case, *I'd strongly suggest that you have whatever app you plan to use the data in do the pivoting, not T-SQL.* (SSRS and Excel can both do it themselves, and code can be written to do it in .NET langauges.) T-SQL, as you have seen, does not lend itself to dynamic pivoting.

What you have will "work" in the sense that it will execute without errors, but there's another downside, in the next stage of your app:  not only will the number of columns potentially change over time, the *names* of the columns will change, as countries move in and out of Card ID 55.  That may cause problems for whatever app or destination you have in mind for this data.

So, my two suggestions would be: either hard-code your country codes, or have the next stage in your app (whatever executes the query) do the actual pivoting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the columns while creating the dynamic SQL

Also:

- Do not use variable coalescing, use `STRING_AGG` or `FOR XML` instead
- Use `QUOTENAME` to escape the column names
- `sp_executesql` allows you to pass parameters to the dynamic query

```sql
DECLARE @idList nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT
    @idList = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(CountryCodeISO3), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CountryCodeISO3)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT CountryCodeISO3
        FROM
            Published.RateCardsValues
        WHERE
            CardID = 55
    ) AS SRC;
    
DECLARE @sqlToRun nvarchar(MAX);

SET
    @sqlToRun = '
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
       [ResourceCode]
      ,[TITLES]
      ,[MostRepresentativeTitle]
      ,[ABBR_RES_DESC]
      ,[TypicalJobGrade]
      ,[BidGridResourceCode]
      ,[OpUnit]
      ,[PSResType]
      ,[JobGradeORResCat]
      ,[CountryCodeISO3]
      --,[CurrencyCode]
      ,[RateValue]

    FROM 
        [Published].[RateCardsValues] rc
    WHERE 
        CardID = 55) As src
PIVOT ( 
    MAX(RateValue) FOR [CountryCodeISO3] IN (' + @idList + ')  
) AS pvt' 

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlToRun;
```

On earlier versions of SQL Server, you cannot use `STRING_AGG`. You need to hack it with `FOR XML`. You need to also use `STUFF` to strip off the first separator.

```sql
DECLARE @idList nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @separator nvarchar(20) = ',';

SET @idList = 
  STUFF(
    (
        SELECT
            @sep + QUOTENAME(CountryCodeISO3)
        FROM
            Published.RateCardsValues
        WHERE
            CardID = 55
        GROUP BY
            CountryCodeISO3
        ORDER BY
            CountryCodeISO3
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
    1, LEN(@separator), '')
;
    
DECLARE @sqlToRun nvarchar(MAX);

SET
    @sqlToRun = '
SELECT * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
       [ResourceCode]
      ,[TITLES]
      ,[MostRepresentativeTitle]
      ,[ABBR_RES_DESC]
      ,[TypicalJobGrade]
      ,[BidGridResourceCode]
      ,[OpUnit]
      ,[PSResType]
      ,[JobGradeORResCat]
      ,[CountryCodeISO3]
      --,[CurrencyCode]
      ,[RateValue]

    FROM 
        [Published].[RateCardsValues] rc
    WHERE 
        CardID = 55) As src
PIVOT ( 
    MAX(RateValue) FOR [CountryCodeISO3] IN (' + @idList + ')  
) AS pvt' 

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlToRun;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Charlieface! STRING_AGG is awesome.. unfortunately my version is 2016.

Comment: OK given you a solution for that also